# Node Script auto start not working - RPI

Tags: node.js, linux, cron

I have a node script inside /home/pi/Blynk/script.js I've followed various posts online relating using cron and etc/init.d However none seem to be working. The script must be run via sudo, I've checked the log and it shows the command being run, but its not running the script.
Here is what I added to cron

(This cron below runs the Blynk server and works)

`@reboot java -jar /home/pi/server-0.27.1.jar -dataFolder /home/pi/Blynk &`

(This cron runs the script with user root and node yet doesn't work)

`@reboot /usr/bin/sudo -u root -H /usr/bin/node /home/pi/Blynk/script.js`

Could someone please show me where I've gone wrong?

Comment: This probably belongs on another SE site, like https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Don't suppose an Admin could move it over? Takes 40 mins to re-post

Comment: To which crontab file did you add that line? Is `sudo` set up to run without interaction/password?